# Organising object data by timestep, so as to chart multiple sensor readings against time using Chart JS

Tags: javascript

I am creating a line chart using the Chart JS library. The data I am using is coming from two different temperature sensors (sensor 1 and sensor 2), that may not necessarily have the same timestamps. I want to split the data into 3 arrays:
1. Sensor 1 readings 
2. Sensor 2 readings 
3. Timestamps

If there is no value at a particular timestep then for one of the sensors for the other the array should have a blank value like at index 1 of this array: [0, ,1,2]

Here is an example of the data:

```js
zdata =
    { "data": [
        {
          "timestamp": 10,
          "sensor_id": 1,
          "temp": 14.5,
        },
        {
          "timestamp": 20,
          "sensor_id": 1,
          "temp": 18,
        },
        {
          "timestamp": 30,
          "sensor_id": 1,
          "temp": 25.5,
        },
        {
          "timestamp": 5,
          "sensor_id": 2,
          "temp": 24.5,
        },
        {
          "timestamp": 20,
          "sensor_id": 2,
          "temp": 29.5,
        }
      ]
    };
```

And how I want the arrays to turn out:

Timestamp: [5,10,20,30]

Sensor 1: [,14.5,18,25.5]

Sensor 2: [24.5,,29.5,]

I also need the number of sensors to change dynamically, so, for example, the data could come in with 3 sensor readings and I would need an extra array to be generated.

So far I attempted the following, however, the 'result.temp' operation is returning an undefined value so the code does works.

```js
var unique_timestamps = [...new Set(zdata.data.map(item => item.timestamp))];
console.log(unique_timestamps);

var sensors = [...new Set(zdata.data.map(item => item.sensor_id))];
console.log(sensors);

// Will hold final arrays of sensor readings
var temperature_datasets = [];

for (i = 0; i < sensors.length; i++) {

    // Holds the array of temperatures for one sensor
    readings_arr =[];

    for (j = 0; j < unique_timestamps.length; j++) {

        var result = zdata.data.filter(obj => {
            return (obj.timestamp === unique_timestamps[j] && obj.sensor_id === sensors[i])
        })
        readings_arr[j]=result.temp;

    }

    temperature_datasets[i] = readings_arr

}
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there a more efficient way of doing this that will take fewer operations?
2. If not, why am I getting an undefined result for 'result.temp' and how can I get the temperature value.

Comment: FYI, JSON is a string format; you are dealing with objects and arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modern ES6 version that gets you the same result and is *hopefully* more readable and is more performant.

Code is explained as comments.
Initially, we pivot an object with time stamp as key and sensor as values.
We then use this to get the timestamp array and an array of sensorValues as shown.

```js
zdata =
    { "data": [
        {
          "timestamp": 10,
          "sensor_id": 1,
          "temp": 14.5,
        },
        {
          "timestamp": 20,
          "sensor_id": 1,
          "temp": 18,
        },
        {
          "timestamp": 30,
          "sensor_id": 1,
          "temp": 25.5,
        },
        {
          "timestamp": 5,
          "sensor_id": 2,
          "temp": 24.5,
        },
        {
          "timestamp": 20,
          "sensor_id": 2,
          "temp": 29.5,
        }
      ]
    };
    
 let {sensors ,...sensorTimeMap} = zdata.data.reduce((acc,val) => {
    if(!acc[val.timestamp]) 
       acc[val.timestamp] = {};
    acc[val.timestamp][val.sensor_id] = val.temp; // pivots the data against timestamp so as to give us more performant lookups later
    if(!acc.sensors.includes(val.sensor_id))
       acc.sensors.push(val.sensor_id)
    return acc;
 },{ sensors:[] }); // Since the number of sensors is dynamic and should be extracted from the data object, we collect available sensors in an array and also create a timeStampMap for future reference
 
 let timestamp = Object.keys(sensorTimeMap); // All timestamps of the pivot generated
 let sensorValArray = sensors.map(sensor => (Object.values(sensorTimeMap).map(obj => obj[sensor] || ''))); // gives us an array of arrays since we cannot know for sure how many sensors are there beforehand and cannot store in different variables. But this is the only way to handle dynamic length since we cannot know how many variables to declare beforehand!
 
 console.log(timestamp,sensorValArray);
```

Comment: Answers without explanation are generally not upvoted as often as those with explanation.

Comment: Hi Dhananjai Pai, that has solved my problem in a much neater way. Thank you very much.

Comment: #@HereticMonkey I have added the explanation in the code. I wanted to give the solution as fast as possible and explain later

Comment: @NiamhDonnelly glad to help. Feel free to upvote / accept the answer if it has helped you solve the problem. Do ask if you need more clarity.

Comment: Great, I will once I have enough reputation points, I am new to posting on stack-overflow.

Comment: Hi @DhananjaiPai, Say I now have a new reading of humidity as well as temperature. For example, areading would be {
          "timestamp": 20,
          "sensor_id": 1,
          "temp": 18, "humidity":12
        } .  I have edited the 4th line of the function to be acc[val.timestamp][val.sensor_id] = [val.temp,val.humidity]. Now, instead of having just the one sensorValArray I want two separate arrays with tempValArray and humidity. I cant seem to figure out how to index the mapped object. Can you help with this?

Comment: @Niamh I am unable to understand the scenario. Would be happy to help. Can you post a new question with sample data and expected output ?

Comment: Hi @DhananjaiPai, thanks so much. I have added a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723799/how-to-use-a-javascript-map-functionality-for-multiple-values