# How to use a javascript map functionality for multiple values

Tags: javascript

I have sensor data in the following format:

```html
zdata =
    { "data": [
            {
                "timestamp": 10,
                "sensor_id": 1,
                "temp": 14.5,
                "hum":13,
                "light":11,
            },
            {
                "timestamp": 20,
                "sensor_id": 1,
                "temp": 18,
                "hum":12,
                "light":20,
            },
            {
                "timestamp": 5,
                "sensor_id": 2,
                "temp": 24.5,
                "hum":12,
                "light":15,
            },
            {
                "timestamp": 20,
                "sensor_id": 2,
                "temp": 29.5,
                "hum":12,
                "light":2,
            }
        ]
    };
```

I using Chart js to display the sensor readings. The data I am using is coming from two different sensor_ids (sensor 1 and sensor 2), that may not necessarily have the same timestamps. Each sensor sends readings for light, humidity, and temperature. I need to plot the readings for both sensors on a graph against the time, so would need the above data like so:

Timestamps = [5, 10, 20]

Sensors = [1,2]

tempValueArray = [ [ '', 14.5, 18 ], [ 24.5, '', 29.5 ] ]

humidityValueArray = [ [ '', 13, 18 ], [ 24.5, '', 29.5 ] ]

lightValueArray = [ [ '', 13, 12 ], [ 12, '', 12 ] ]

Initially, I was just using a temperature sensor using a time map and the code posted as the answer here: [Organising object data by timestep, so as to chart multiple sensor readings against time using Chart JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54594804/organising-object-data-by-timestep-so-as-to-chart-multiple-sensor-readings-agai)

However, I have updated the code here to loop through each type of reading (i.e. temp, hum, light):

```js
var sensorNames = ['temp','hum','light'];
var allSensors = [];

for (i = 0; i < sensorNames.length; i++) {
    let {sensors ,...sensorTimeMap} = zdata.data.reduce((acc,val) => {
        sensorTypes = [val.temp, val.hum, val.light];
        if(!acc[val.timestamp]) acc[val.timestamp] = {};
        acc[val.timestamp][val.sensor_id] = sensorTypes[i];
        if(!acc.sensors.includes(val.sensor_id))
            acc.sensors.push(val.sensor_id)
        return acc;
    },{sensors:[]}); // get available sensors and create a timeStamp map for future iterations

    let timestamp = Object.keys(sensorTimeMap);
    allSensors.push(sensors.map(sensor => (Object.values(sensorTimeMap).map(obj => obj[sensor] || ''))));


};

console.log(sensors);
console.log(allSensors);
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this loop? I am new to javascript so am unsure how to add a number of readings in the map and save each to a new array.